# getting an exception while creating a Facebook mobile ad

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to create a **mobile ad** using Facebook Ads API.
I send a post request to: graph.facebook.com/act_XXX/adgroups
with the parameters:

name:     x 
bid_type: CPC 
bid_info: {"CLICKS":2} 
conversion_specs: [{"action.type":["mobile_app_install"],"application":["xxx"]}] 
campaign_id: xxx 
tracking_specs: [{"action.type":["mobile_app_install"],"application":["xxx"]}] 
targeting: {"geo_locations":{"countries":['US']}} 
creative: {"creative_id":"xxx"}

but all of a sudden I get this error:

**{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error occurred", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 1, 
    "error_subcode": 1487810
  }
}**

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Error Subcode 1487810 corresponds to this message:

Summary: The creative provided requires a different objective

Message: This creative requires an objective that corresponds with the creative provided. E.g, MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS.

What this means is that the "Campaign" (the one you create with the campaign_groups endpoint) needs to have an objective set to MOBILE_APP_INSTALLS.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile app install ads need a `user_device` and `user_os` field in the targeting specs. Also, if you set the action.type as "mobile_app_install", you must use CPA or oCPM bidding.

Comment: sure I use user_device and user_os fields And I also use CPA but it still doesn't work.. –

Answer (score -2):

If your URL goes to the appstore or the google market, then you need change objective.